# swap strings of text inside vim using regex

Tags: files, regular-expression, quoting

I am working with a file where I need to swap "string A" and "String B's" locations simultaneously with a regex inside the vim. Here is an example line of code:

```
succ_1st=`grep 'resulted in successful answer' $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp | sed '/localhost.localdomain/,/testdns.net/{//!d}' | awk '{ print $1 }' |grep -m1 ''`
```

I need it to look like this:

```
succ_1st=`sed '/localhost.localdomain/,/testdns.net/{//!d}' $path_tmp/named.stats.tmp | grep 'resulted in successful answer' | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -m1 ''`
```

The grep and sed statements in each line are identical, I just need to swap locations of each. I can do this with sed outside my file but I need to be able to do this with regex inside the vim. Here is what I have tried:

```
%s/grep 'search string'/sed '\/search string\/,\/search string\/{\/\/!d}'/g
```

This only REPLACES and not swaps:

I have also tried :

```
%s/\v(grep[^$]*)([$][^|]*)[|] (sed[^|]*)/\3\2| \1/
```

Which fails and returns:

```
E486: Pattern not found: \v(grep[^$]*)([$][^|]*)[|] (sed[^|]*)
```

Please do not mark this as duplicate, vote to close, downvote, etc.. as it is not a dup. All other threads deal with doing this using sed which is not what I want.

EDIT -- Note that I am invoking Vim using a Vi alias which points to /usr/bin/vim.

Comment: `%s/\v(grep[^$]*)([$][^|]*)[|] (sed[^|]*)/\3\2| \1/` worked perfectly for me. Did you run it as `vi` or `vim`?

Comment: I'm using Vim. Well, more accurately, an alias that points vi to /usr/bin/vim - but that should not make a difference I would not think.

Comment: @user53029 It does make a difference, Vim behaves differently when invoked under the name `vi`. If you want all Vim features, run `vim`, not `vi`, even if it's the same executable. Does running `vim` make a difference? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Question edited. Will have to test tomorrow and report back. Thanks all!

Comment: running with Vim makes no difference - I am still getting the E486 error shown above.